# How to find JNDI name in JBoss-7?

Tags: jboss7.x

**Please find the scenario below,**

```
@Stateless(name = "TestManager")
@Remote(TestInterfaceRemote.class)
@Local(TestInterfaceLocal.class)
public class TestManagerBean implements TestInterfaceLocal, TestInterfaceRemote {}
```

The following JNDI name for the TestManagerBean class which is printed in server.log file if the server log level is INFO. By using this JNDI, I am able to access the bean in the EJB client program.

*java:global/Sample/Demo/TestManager!net.juniper.jmp.test.TestInterfaceRemote*

**My question is,**

How to find same JNDI names in JBoss-7 setup? Do we have any console to know the all JNDI's in JBoss?

I tried to find JNDI names by using jconsole mode but there's only EJB name not fully qualified JNDI name on it.

Could you please give me an IDEA if we have an option to know JNDI names in JBoss-7?

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (JBoss AS 7.3.0.Final) the web administration console provides a JNDI View:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting an error such as "Failed to Load JNDI Information" when i click on JNDI View option. Do i need to an enable any option to view JNDI information?

Comment: Hi @Azhaguvel A for me this option is enabled by default, any configurarion extra is need.

Comment: Let me know your JBoss configuration detail for <datasource jndi-name="..">. Which is in standalone.xml file. I think, there is some configuration for java:global part.

Comment: @Azhaguvel A my datasources are not java:global. In picture my datasources are alclogds and ceos_gip_ds, both under "java:".