# javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: EJBCLIENT000079 Eclipse, JBOSS,EJB 3.1

Tags: java, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

[javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: EJBCLIENT000079 with JBoss 7.1 and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55022384/javax-ejb-nosuchejbexception-ejbclient000079-with-jboss-7-1-and-eclipse#)

My test code is exactly same as given in the above post and the problem i am facing was also mentioned in the same post but do not see any confirmed solution.

please let me know if you have any solutions/ideas.

Comment: When you start your app server you should find log statement with all JNDI paths of that EJB:
 java:global/HelloWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean!com.ibytecode.business.HelloWorld etc.

Check if one of logged JNDI paths is same as the one you have defined in your test class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @petr-freiberg . I noticed there was some difference in the JNDI path and changed it but after this i am getting the below error..                                                                         Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.wildfly.naming.client.store.RelativeContext cannot be cast to com.sample.ejb.HelloWorld
 at com.sample.client.Client.dolookup(Client.java:34)
 at com.sample.client.Client.main(Client.java:22)

Comment: Please past code with lookup.

Comment: `public class ClientUtility {
 
 public static Context initialContext;
 private static final String PKG_INTERFACES = "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming";
 
 public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException{
  if(initialContext == null){
   Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, PKG_INTERFACES);
   properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
   initialContext = new InitialContext(properties);
  }
  return initialContext;
 }

}`

Comment: `public class Client {
 public static void main(String []srgs){}
 
 private static HelloWorld dolookup(){
  Context context = null;
  HelloWorld intface = null;
  
  try{
   context = ClientUtility.getInitialContext();
   String lookupName = "ejb:HellowWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean!com.sample.ejb.HelloWorld";      
    //same as JNDI shownon server log
   intface = (HelloWorld)context.lookup(lookupName);
  }catch(NamingException e){
   
  }
  return intface;
 }
 } `

Comment: please check     @petr-freiberg

Comment: Try this: java:global/name-of-your-jar/HelloWorldSessionBean!com.sample.ejb.HelloWorld;

I assume that this "HelloWorldSessionBean" is name of your class and "HelloWorld" is name of your interface. Name of jar is without extension. So for example if your jar is named "my_Test.jar" then java:global/my_Test/HelloWorldSessionBean!com.sample.ejb.HelloWorld;

Comment: @PetrFreiberg                                                                                                                   using "java:global/HellowWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean!com.sample.ejb.HelloWorld" as lookup name returns with null interface reference and causes null pointer exception.                                                                                                                         HellowWorldSessionBean is my jar name, HelloWorldBean is the implementation class and HelloWorld is the interface.

Comment: java:global/HellowWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean!com.sample.ejb.HelloWorld

Try this please.

Comment: @PetrFreiberg -  tried it but did not work. i can see this lookup name in the JNDI binding log on server console.

Comment: OK, let's try different approach:
Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080/"); // please double-check IP and PORT of your Wildfly
jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
jndiProperties.put("org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context", "true");

Comment: Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
HelloWorld bean=(HelloWorld)context.lookup("/HellowWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean!com.sample.ejb.HelloWorld");

Comment: @PetrFreiberg - after doing the above changes it worked.                                                         Thanks a lot for your prompt response on this.                                                                                                                                                              
    It works also when in my previous code i add the PROVIDER_URL property and  changed the look up name to "/HellowWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean!com.sample.ejb.HelloWorld"        or "ejb:/HellowWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean!com.sample.ejb.HelloWorld"  .

Comment: @PetrFreiberg  Can u tell me what is the reason i had to do the above changes to make it work, for my better understanding??

Comment: I think without setting PROVIDER_URL the client did not know where to look for the server. I'm glad it helped. I will post it as an answer to this thread for others who would encounter the same problem. Have a great day ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080/"); // double-check IP and PORT of your app server; you may need to use remote+http or remote+https
jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
jndiProperties.put("org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context", "true"); 

Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties); 
HelloWorld bean=(HelloWorld)context.lookup("/HellowWorldSessionBean/HelloWorldBean!com.sample.ejb.HelloWorld");
```